# Python IndexError for slicing the array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have an array that I would like to take a portion of each element of the array.

```
id = [000222000,000333000,000444000]

id2 = [222,333,444]
```

In order to be able to get id2 array I am using a for loop as follows:

```
id2 = [i[3:5] for i in id]
```

However, I get an IndexError: invalid index to a scalar variable. I don't understand why am I getting this error and how to overcome it? Also is it a same principle if I have array of strings instead of numbers?

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was just a simple example, I am converting it from another programming language and things got messy a bit. It is annoying that we can slice the string but not the integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't slice numbers in python. If you want to slice the elements, you could cast everything to a string, slice them, then cast everything back to an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is annoying that we can slice the string but not the integer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to slice integers, which is not possible as of right now in python 3.x

P.S

-It is not a good practice to name your list id as it is a used function in python.
-Try changing everything to Strings if you want to slice.. + change it from [3:5] to [3:6] as it does not include the last index, so you are only selecting two digits and not 3 as I suppose you want..
- It is not possible to have leading zeros in decimal base in python.